# Use Volume label rather than drive letter

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, disk-management

My home system changes quite often, particularly, drive letters get reassigned.

e.g. My large volume of music is on (Neptune) K:\music.  That's where Windows media player expects it, today.

Is there a way to tell Windows Media player (or any program) to look on a drive by its label, Neptune, vs by its letter K: which will change tomorrow?

I tried in Disk Management, but the letter K: is now neither used nor available. It's not in explorer. I see it, in DM, as a sort of blank.  I changed *its* drive letter to Z: then mine to K:.  But I'm afraid I'll use up all my drive letters quickly this way.

Otherwise I'm obliged to tell WMP the new letter, whatever Windows picks, and it takes quite a while to reindex all that data that hasn't actually changed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cant have application use the name of the volume to recognize drives.

I believe your issues are being caused unwittingly by yourself.

Windows Disk Management will try to mount drive to letters it assigned to them before.  If at some point you reused a letter, perhaps you plugged in a USB drive and it give it K:, then another day you plugged in another drive, and it got J:, but you changed it to K: ... etc... It could be that Windows helpfulness is hindering you.

Long story short, take a moment and attach all your drives and then manually assign the drive letters you want and you should no longer have this issue.

Comment: yup, this is the correct solution .. +1